# WCF Service - Coding Standard - Where to put my class library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to implement a WCF Service in my program , howevery I don't understand something:

According to the book "Programming WCF Services" , Juval Löwy 2007 O'Reilly Media,.
Appendix C. - WCF Coding Standard  C2 - Essential :
1. Place service code in a class library and not in any hosting EXE.

I don't understand this, where should I put my code? all my class are defined in my form application , How should I call my classes of the winforms from the Class Library of the service.

Am I missing here something??

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit confusing.

We're talking about the service implementation here. What Loewy means here is that the code to implement the service should be in a separate project. The code that hosts the WCF service (i.e. the class that implements your service contract) should do nothing but call that service implementation code.

So your Windows Forms client application uses a proxy, which in turn calls the WCF service application hosting layer, which in turn calls your service logic.

It's a very good idea to go further and have three layers on the UI side and four on the service side. The namespaces might be

```
Company.Project.UI.WinForms
Company.Project.UI
Company.Project.ServiceClient

Company.Project.ServiceHost
Company.Project.Service
Company.Project.BusinessLogic
Company.Project.Persistence
```

For simpler projects this would be overkill, but for anything more than (say) one form or two service methods it will make life much easier. Not least, testing each layer in isolation should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the explanation, what is Company.Project.Persistence layer for ?

Comment: Database storage, or similar. It might call another service - I've written plenty of services that call services for persistence recently rather than doing database work directly.

Comment: And also: per @Jason, it's important to make sure that each layer references only the one below it. An IoC framework like Spring.NET or Castle Windsor can really help there.

Comment: BTW - what is Castle Windsor ?

Comment: It's an inversion of control container: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Answer (score 5):

I like to structure my WCF solutions like this:

**YourProject.Contracts** (class library)
Contains all the service, operations, fault, and data contracts. Can be shared between server and client in a pure .NET-to-.NET scenario

**YourProject.Service** (class library)
Contains the code to implement the services, and any support/helper methods needed to achieve this. Nothing else.

**YourProject.ServiceHost** (optional - can be Winforms, Console App, NT Service)
Contains service host(s) for debugging/testing, or possibly also for production.

This basically gives me the server-side of things.

On the client side:

**YourClient.ClientProxies** (class library)
I like to package my client proxies into a separate class library, so that they can be reused by multiple actual client apps. This can be done using svcutil or "Add Service Reference" and manually tweaking the resulting horrible app.config's, or by doing manual implementation of client proxies (when sharing the contracts assembly) using `ClientBase<T>` or `ChannelFactory<T>` constructs.

**1-n actual clients** (any type of app)
Will typically only reference the client proxies assembly, or maybe the contracts assembly, too, if it's being shared. This can be ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms, console app, other services - you name it.

That way; I have a nice and clean layout, I use it consistently over and over again, and I really think this has made my code cleaner and easier to maintain.

This was inspired by Miguel Castro's [Extreme WCF screen cast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) on DotNet Rocks TV with Carl Franklin - highly recommended screen cast !

Comment: Yes, breaking out the contracts to a different assembly so they can be re-used makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical project structure following Löwy's recommendation:

```
MyProject.Data
MyProject.Logic
MyProject.Services
MyProject.ServiceHosts
MyProject.Presentation
```

Then `MyProject.ServiceHosts` will reference `MyProject.Services` and exposes the services defined there. So in Löwy's language, `MyProject.Services` is the class library, and `MyProject.ServiceHosts` contains the hosting executable.

Comment: Quick question:  My Service needs to call another, external, service.  This client proxy is required in my Logic layer - but that means I also need the config sections in both the Logic layer's app.config and my service layers web.config?  Is that the correct way to do things?